# cakephp link on image escape is not working

Tags: javascript, cakephp

Image link in the cakephp is not working

```
$this->Html->link(  
      $this->Html->image('image',array('class' => $class,
                'id' =>'img_id' )), somelink, array('onclick' =>'jQuery(this).modal({width:600,height:400,left:120,top:100}).open(); return false;'),
                                        array(),
                                        array('escape'=>false));
```

it will output

```
<a href='link' onclick='jQuery(this).modal({width:600,height:400}).open(); return false;'> &lt; img src='image_path' &gt;
```

it is not escaping &lt and >  even if i mention escape=>false,  but i am not getting where i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many arguements. Try this:

```
echo $this->Html->link(  
  $this->Html->image('image',array('class' => $class,
            'id' =>'img_id' )), 'foo', array('escape'=>false, 'onclick' =>'jQuery(this).modal({width:600,height:400,left:120,top:100}).open(); return false;')
);
```

Comment: Read the API here: http://api.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelperlink

Comment: So my answer fixed your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $this->Html->link(  
 $this->Html->image('image',array('class' => $class,
        'id' =>'img_id' )), '#', array('escape'=>false, 'onclick' => 'jQuery(this).modal({width:600,height:400,left:120,top:100}).open(); return false;','class'=>'linkclass'));
```